# unknown type name 'siginfo_t' with Clang using _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2, why?

Tags: c, clang, c99

**Update**  Turnes out my lecturer will accept code written to the GNU99 standard, so, as User1 pointed out, I used `_GNU_SOURCE` at the beginning of my program.  (See `man feature_test_macros` for more info.)  Thanks for helping me understand!

On Ubuntu 13.10 with Clang 3.4, GCC 4.8.1, I am doing an assignment which requires me to use the C99 standard. (I also have GNUstep installed from SVN)

WRT GCC, I think I have 4 versions installed in these folders:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7.3
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.1
```

`gcc --version` reports 4.8.1, `clang --version` reports 3.4.  `ld -v` reports 2.23.52.20130913

I'm writing a signal handler and when I use siginfo_t in my function header, I get a compiler error: `unknown type name 'siginfo_t'`  I'm using sigaction() to install the handler.

While studying what needs to be done and how, I was able to compile a simple demo which also uses the same function header definition, and it works.  However it's not limited to C99.

These are my includes (of which signal.h is one):

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <signal.h>
```

This is my signal handler function (*only for debugging purposes*):

```
static void sigSIGCHLDhandler(int sigNum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context) {

        printf("PID = %ld",(long) siginfo->si_pid);

}
```

I am compiling with `clang` using `-Wall` and <strike>`-std=c99`</strike> now `-std=gnu99`options.

I have tried `locate signal.h` and I have it in `/usr/include`. I tried adding `#include <bits/siginfo.h>` and that allowed me to compile, but the binary wouldn't work correctly.
(I have a bunch of `signal.h` and `siginfo.h` files on my system.)

Another student suggested that there is something wrong with my set up.  So I've reinstalled Clang.  Here are some of my environment variables that I think might be relevant (**please notify me of any missing or wrong**)

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib:/home/user/GNUstep/Library/Libraries:/usr/local/lib
CPATH=/home/user/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include
PATH=/home/user/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/bin:/home/user/GNUstep/Tools:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin
CLASSPATH=/home/user/GNUstep/Library/Libraries/Java:/usr/local/lib/GNUstep/Libraries/Java
LIBRARY_COMBO=gnu-gnu-gnu
INFOPATH=/usr/local/share/info::/home/user/GNUstep/Library/Documentation/info:
GNUSTEP_IS_FLATTENED=yes
GNUSTEP_LOCAL_ROOT=/usr/local/Local
GNUSTEP_HOST=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
GUILE_LOAD_PATH=/home/user/GNUstep/Library/Libraries/Guile:/usr/local/lib/GNUstep/Libraries/Guile
GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES=/usr/local/share/GNUstep/Makefiles
GNUSTEP_NETWORK_ROOT=/usr/local/Network
GNUSTEP_FLATTENED=yes
GNUSTEP_HOST_OS=linux-gnu
GNUSTEP_HOST_VENDOR=unknown
GNUSTEP_HOST_CPU=x86_64
GNUSTEP_USER_ROOT=/home/user/GNUstep
GNUSTEP_SYSTEM_ROOT=/usr/local/System
GNUSTEP_PATHLIST=/usr/local/System:/usr/local/Network:/usr/local/Local:/home/user/GNUstep
GNUSTEP_SYSTEM_ROOT=/usr/local/System
GNUSTEP_PATHLIST=/usr/local/System:/usr/local/Network:/usr/local/Local:/home/nap/GNUstep
```

I've spent hours searching for a fix but can't find anything, and I'm out of ideas.
What is broken?

Comment: There is nothing in the C standard called siginfo or signinfo_t. So your question isn't related to C99 as such. I know very little of these libraries, but it would seem that siginfo.h is some non-standard library.

Comment: Ok. From the man page,, the feature test macros are: `sigaction(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE` and `siginfo_t: _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L`.  So, what you're saying is that though the C99 standard came after both of these, it does not include POSIX? I'm currently reading Wiki to get an idea of how the different standards relate to each other and hopefully understand more about this. (It's been driving me nuts for a while now.)

Comment: Indeed the C standard does not know/care about POSIX. C doesn't even require an OS to be present.

Comment: I had a similar problem and changing `-std=c99` to `-std=gnu99` fixed things. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look the man page of sigaction(2), you will find the following:

> siginfo_t: _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L

Try adding the compiler option: `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L`

It tells  the required posix version to your c-lib (glibc).

EDIT:

See more about those from [POSIX wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

`featuers.h` tells more about how glibc use the define:

```
   _POSIX_C_SOURCE  
          If ==1, like _POSIX_SOURCE; 
          if >=2 add IEEE Std 1003.2;
          if >=199309L, add IEEE Std 1003.1b-1993;
          if >=199506L, add IEEE Std 1003.1c-1995;
          if >=200112L, all of IEEE 1003.1-2004
```

Similar information also in man page: [feature_test_macros(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros).

So: _POSIX_C_SOURCE=2 does not bring latest POSIX features for available, because 1003.2 (posix 2) is not the latest one. For getting more features available you need to define later version.

Don't get confused: POSIX.2 is not newer than POSIX.1c.

Comment: I will try that, but could you explain why my _POSIX_C_SOURCE 2 doesn't already cover that? For my assignment, I have to produce C99 compliant code which my lecturer tests on OSX 10.9.2.  (This means that I can't even use the BSD_SOURCE option.)

Comment: Turns out our lecturer will accept code written to the gnu99 standard.  So I've used _GNU_SOURCE at the beginning of my program.