# Problem while using siginfo_t error , as Compiler couldn't detect this keyword

Tags: c, linux, header, signals, gnu

While working on the `.c` files I encountered the problem with `siginfo_t`.
The header file I am using are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <gnu/libc-version.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <ucontext.h> 
#include "libapiinc.h"
```

The header files are configured properly.
The snapshot of small part of code is as follows:

```
static void sighandler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr)
```

[image: Image showing problem in code]

As I know the Siginfo comes under the signal header file, I have configured that includes properly.

What should be done to resolve the error of this `siginfo_t`? Which appears as **Type siginfo_t couldn't be resolved**

Comment: Don't post pictures of code and errors, post them as actual text.

Comment: Do note that your signal handler invokes undefined behavior. `fprintf()` is async-signal-unsafe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unknown type name 'siginfo\_t' with Clang using \_POSIX\_C\_SOURCE 2, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912674/unknown-type-name-siginfo-t-with-clang-using-posix-c-source-2-why)